# How to set HttpHeaders data to every Custom Request Class in WebFlux APIS?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive

In my APIs, there is custom request class for each APIs, I want to write code which gets fields from `HttpHeaders` from upcoming request and set that set of fields to that particular **Request class**, so it will do this for all request classes.

I have done this in MVC code, but don't know how to do this for **reactive** APIs with **WebFlux**(Library- Project Reactor).

Controller:

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<JsonNode>> getData(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders header, GetDataRequest request){
  .... // all stuff
 }
```

now some data are coming from `header` like `type`, `token`, `comID`, etc.
I want to set these fields to Request Class `GetDataRequest` before further processing of the request as I will need these fields further,
but this request class different for all the requests, so I need common code, which set this to any request class which is passed to it.
Note: not using `WebClient` here, only `Flux` and `Mono` are there.

So basically, get fields from a header which is of type `HttpHeaders`, set these data to particular request class, but do this in WebFlux Framework, reactive APIS.
Please help anyone.

Comment: Have you considered to write a custom ArgumentResolver to accomplish this? I assume it could be possible to write custom logic for object creation from the incoming request there.

Comment: @martinnemec3 No, I haven't considered that, can you please guide me for it, how can  I do that?

Comment: I just posted an answer describing the suggested approach - it can be adapted dependening on your concrete needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

1. define some base class for your requests that would have attributes you want to store headers values in, e.g.:

   ```
   public class MyAbstractRequest {
       private String header1;
       private String header2;
       // ...
       // getters and setters
   }
   ```
2. inherit all you request classes from this class, e.g.:

   ```
   public class GetDataRequest extends MyAbstractRequest {
       // GetDataRequest content here
   }
   ```
3. create an argumentResolver for all those classes that inherit from `MyAbstractRequest`. To ensure the behavior is same as for normal request body deserialization use `AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver` as a base class:

   ```
    public class MyArgumentResolver extends AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver {

      public MyArgumentResolver(List<HttpMessageReader<?>> messageReaders, ReactiveAdapterRegistry adapterRegistry) {
        super(messageReaders, adapterRegistry);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return MyAbstractRequest.class.isAssignableFrom(parameter.getParameterType());
      }

      @Override
      public Mono<Object> resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, BindingContext bindingContext, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return readBody(parameter, true, bindingContext, exchange)
          .map(o -> {
            // your headers extraction logic here ...
            ((MyAbstractRequest) o).setHeader1(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("header1"));
            ((MyAbstractRequest) o).setHeader2(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("header2"));
            return o;
          });
       }
    }
   ```
4. configure your `MyArgumentResolver` in the webflux configuration:

   ```
    @Configuration
    public class WebFluxConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {

      @Autowired
      ApplicationContext applicationContext;

      @Override
      public void configureArgumentResolvers(ArgumentResolverConfigurer configurer) {
        ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer = applicationContext.getBean(ServerCodecConfigurer.class);
        ReactiveAdapterRegistry reactiveAdapterRegistry = applicationContext.getBean("webFluxAdapterRegistry", ReactiveAdapterRegistry.class);
        configurer.addCustomResolver(new MyArgumentResolver(serverCodecConfigurer.getReaders(), reactiveAdapterRegistry));
      }
    }
   ```
5. Now your requests should get injected into the controller methods with the configured resolver:

   ```
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<JsonNode>> getData(GetDataRequest request){
    }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but ReactiveAdapterRegistry is giving an error. how to register bean of webFluxAdapterRegistry?

Comment: Do you have 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux' dependency in your project.

Comment: Yes. I have this dependency in my project.

Comment: Then both the webFluxAdapterRegistry bean and ServerCodecConfigurer bean should be both present in the spring context (you do not need to instantiate it manually). I created a simple project for demonstration how it works: https://github.com/martinnemec3/spring-argument-resolver-demo

Comment: Thank you so much for this demonstration. I tried the same. and annotated MyArgumentResolver class with @Component then it's giving an error for HttpMessageReader and webFluxAdapterRegistry, but if not annotating class then Not giving error, but not setting header too. I am not getting what's wrong.

Comment: what header do you try to extract? Do you have it correctly spelled in the `MyArgumentResolver`'s `resolveArgument` method?

Comment: I'm passing company_id and trying to extract it. yes correctly spelled. will this class require any annotation or not?

Comment: The `MyArgumentResolver` class requires no annotation (it's instantiated in the configurer class during the webflux configuration phase) as you can see it in the code (step 4 of this post) - so no annotation. You can clone the github repository I've sent to verify it works.

Comment: I tried your demo project. it's giving 415 Unsupported media type error. Error is before request processing, means somewhere in argument resolver, debugged it but not able catch where is it exactly. and If I tried your code in my project then no error but not setting header too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234325/discussion-between-taslim-sama-and-martinnemec3).